# Which one is synchronous or asynchronous communication ? And Why?

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, web, microservices, synchronous

I am confuse about both communication for the given scenario.I feel that every single list item can be synchronous communication.

- Order service calling the shipping service to proceed for shipment.

  - User buying items from User Interface(UI) Service resulting in
    invocation of Order Service.
  - User Interface(UI) service calling catalog service to get information
    about all of the items that it needs to render.

Answer (score 1):

All three examples would be considered asynchronous as they prompt a response due to cause and effect - call and respond. While all three of these could happen concurrently, each in and of themselves is not synchronous.

Synchronous communication happens simultaneously, like two people editing the same document online. Each editor reads and writes at the same time, but does not interrupt the other in any way.

The best example of synchronous communication is a telephone conversation. All connected parties **can hear (receive) & speak (transmit) at the same time**, and although humans have difficulting performing both actions simultaneously, the telephone connection itself has no trouble providing both concurrently.

Asynchronous acts like a two-way radio. You must stop transmitting in order to receive.

Answer (score 0):

**Synchronous** = in synch

- Sender wait for a response from the receiver to continue further.
- Both Sender and Receiver should be in active state.
- Sender send data to receiver as it requires an immediate response to continue processing.
- When you execute something synchronously, you wait for it to finish before moving on to another task.

**Asynchronous** = out of synch

- Sender does not wait for a response from the receiver
- Receiver can be inactive.
- Once Receiver is active, it will receive and process.
- Sender puts data in message queue and does not require an immediate response to continue processing.
- When you execute something asynchronously, you can move on to another task before it finishes.

**In your case,**

Catalog Service <--  UI  -->  Order Service --> Shipment service

1) UI has to fetch item details from Catalog Service (Synchronous because it needs item immedietly)

2) Once all items selected, UI has to invoke Order service.(synchronous / asynchronous, depends upon user action)

- User might add in shopping cart for future use (or) in favourites (or) to immediate process order.

3) Once all items exist in shopping cart collection , it has to invoke shipmentService. (asynchronous)

- Payment should be synchronous. You need acknowledgement.
- Assuming all payment and other stuff done, it calls shipment delivery service
- Delivery is asynchronous because it cant get acknowledge immedietly. It may take 2 days delay etc.